# Error Installing Adafruit_DHT for python on Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I need to use a DHT-11 for a school project and I am getting a weird error trying to install the packages for it.

Following the instructions I used `sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT` and that resulted in this output:

```
sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_DHT
  Using cached Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  Building wheel for Adafruit_DHT (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Adafruit_DHT
  Running setup.py clean for Adafruit_DHT
Failed to build Adafruit_DHT
Installing collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Adafruit_DHT

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I also tried running `sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT --install-option="--force-pi"` which output:

```
WARNING: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_DHT
  Using cached Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Skipping wheel build for Adafruit_DHT, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT ... done
Successfully installed Adafruit_DHT
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

However, when I run my python code I get this

```
  import Adafruit_DHT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

I've updated pip and the setup tools and I'm pretty new to all of this. This assignment is due soon and I just want to get this DHT working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install the Adafruit_DHT on my py.

When I reinstalled wheel with:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

and then:

```
sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because `--install-option="--force-pi"` is deprecated in pip v22.3 and because I was not able to pass the `--force-pi` parameter using `--config-settings` (KEY=VAL format expected) I ended up using this workaround to fake the Pi version during installation:

```bash
echo '>>> Upgrade pip to at least v22.3'
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip # upgrade pip to at least v22.3
echo '>>> Install deprecated DHT library for measurement python scripts'
# deprecated, but still used for Pi Zero WH because of known issues such as https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT/issues/73 - no longer working on bullseye
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel # see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72934737/6696623
# Fake Raspberry Pi version because --install-option="--force-pi" does not work with pip v22.3
echo -e "\nHardware   : BCM2709" >> /etc/cpuinfo # see: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/8f5e2c4d6ebba8836f6d31ec9a0c171948e3237d/Adafruit_DHT/platform_detect.py#L36
if [ -e /etc/cpuinfo ] ; then
  mount --bind /etc/cpuinfo /proc/cpuinfo
fi
pip3 install Adafruit_DHT
pip3 install Adafruit_Python_DHT
```